# Replace px to rem using VSCode search and replacement

Tags: css, regex, visual-studio-code

I have an old css project and it's using `px` as default unit.

Now the project needs to be refurbished and I need to replace all `px` to `rem` using VSCode search and replace, and the ratio is `10px` = `1rem`

`20px` should be converted to `2rem`, but `2.0rem` is also fine, I can just get rid of the trailing `.0`s afterwards.

But if the unit is too small that less than `5px`, I should not replace it.

And yes, there are some decimal points for px for some of the rules... Emit it if it's easier.

- Sample data

```css
font-size: 10px;
border: 0px;
margin-top: 4px;    // dont touch
margin-bottom: 12px;
margin-right: 50%;
margin-left: -12px;
padding-left: 120px;
padding-right: 8px;
border-radius: calc(50% - 1px);   // dont touch
grid-template-columns: 1fr 44px 1fr;
margin-top: 36.4px;
border-width: 10.5px;
border-width: .3px;  // dont touch
border-width: .6px;   // dont touch
border-width: 3.3px;  // dont touch
border-width: 6.6px;
margin-left: -1px;    // dont touch
```

- Desired output after replacement

```css
font-size: 1rem;
border: 0rem;
margin-top: 4px;    // dont touch
margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
margin-right: 50%;
margin-left: -1.2rem;
padding-left: 12rem;
padding-right: .8rem;
border-radius: calc(50% - 1px);   // dont touch
grid-template-columns: 1fr 4.4rem 1fr;
margin-top: 3.64rem;
border-width: 1.05rem;
border-width: .3px;  // dont touch
border-width: .6px;   // dont touch
border-width: 3.3px;  // dont touch
border-width: .66rem;
margin-left: -1px;    // dont touch
```

Here's what I've been trying but still couldn't get it right

```
\b(?![1234]px)(\d*)(\d)(?:\.(\d+))?px\b
```

```
$1.$2$3rem
```

Here's a [test project on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JVoIEs/1/)

Comment: You might use a pattern like `\b(?![1234](?:\.\d+)?px)(?<!(?<!\S)\.)(\d*)(\d)(?:\.(\d+))?px\b` https://regex101.com/r/WmZPR8/1 But note that you can not turn `0px;` into `0rem;` when using the `.` in the replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option might by to use the `.` in the replacement with the groups `$1.$2$3rem` and afterwards replace `.0rem;` with `0rem;`

```
\b(?![1-4](?:\.\d+)?px)(?<!(?<!\S)\.)(\d*)(\d)(?:\.(\d+))?px\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `[1-4](?:\.\d+)?px` Match a digit 1-4  optionally followed by `.` and 1+ digits and `px`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?<!(?<!\S)\.)` Negative lookahead to assert that on the left is not a `.` with a whitespace boundary on the left to prevent a partial match
- `(\d*)(\d)` Capture group 1, match optional digits, and capture a single digit in group 2
- `(?:\.(\d+))?` Optionally matching `.` and capture in group 3 1+ digits
- `px\b` Match `px` followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9jP8fC/1)

Comment: Thanks, works smoothly! I didn't know you can nest lookbehinds.